Changing Display scale from 100% to 125% changes the resolution, according to xrandr
If I change the Display scale setting from 100% to %125%, the resolution according to xrandr increases. This affects full-screen applications and games where they attempt to run at an unsupported/high resolution.
For example, when I set the Display scale to 100%, this is the xrandr output:
DisplayPort-2 connected primary 3440x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 800mm x 334mm
Which is perfect, because that's the correct and supported resolution that my monitor utilizes.
If I change the Display scale to 125%, this is the xrandr output:
DisplayPort-2 connected primary 5504x2304+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 800mm x 334mm
If I run any full-screen application or game at 125% scale, the game attempts to run at 5504x2304, which is unsupported and I wouldn't be able to see the rest of the game until I kill the full screen application.
QUESTION: Did anybody experience this issue and familiar with mitigating it? I'm OK with running 100% scale for now, 125% is just easier on my eyes. This issue doesn't occur if I switch to the Wayland display server on Ubuntu 22.04 and use 125% scale. This only happens if I use x11 instead of Wayland.
EDIT: This is how I change to using x11 instead of Wayland on a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04:
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
#Uncomment this line.
WaylandEnable=false
I then restart so, nothing complicated. If I want to switch back to Wayland I just add the comment back to that line and restart.

If You don't have a multi-monitor configuration with different DPIs - simply -  disable fractional scaling and increase the font size (gnome-tweaks)

Correct, I'm only using a single monitor. I'm OK with 100% scale and zooming using my apps if necessary, no need for gnome-tweaks yet. I'm sticking to x11 to address the screen sharing and on-screen keyboard issues I encountered with Wayland. I just switched from Windows to Ubuntu and it's been an incredible experience so far. This is just a tiny bug I encountered so its not a big deal.
